# Google ColabにおいてPickleを使いたい

Tags: python, python3, numpy, google-colaboratory

タイトルの通り、Google ColabにおいてPickleをインストールして使用したいです。

[Not able to pip install pickle in python 3.6 - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477949/not-able-to-pip-install-pickle-in-python-3-6/48477988)

上記ページを参考にし、以下のコマンドを実行したのですが、pickleがインストールできませんでした。（pickle-mixinのみのインストールは可能でした。）

```
!pip install pickle-mixin
!pip install pickle
```

またその後

```
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
```

とし

```
with open('***.data','rb') as file:
  images,labels = pickle.load(file)
```

のように実行すると以下のエラーが出ます。

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core.multiarray\r'
```

どうすればpickleを使えるようになるでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Colab の環境にも当てはまるのかわかりませんが、リンク先を読む限り "Pickle は標準モジュールになっているので pip でのインストールは必要無い" と書かれているように見えます。「インストールできない」時には何かメッセージ等が表示されていませんか？ / また、(最終的に) 使いたいのが Pickle であってもエラーが出ているのは numpy 関連のエラーに見えます。"やりたいこと" より "起きている問題" に焦点を絞ってタイトルや質問を組み立てた方がより伝わりやすいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。おっしゃるとおりでございました。

Answer (score 1):

[Not able to pip install pickle in python 3.6 - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477949/not-able-to-pip-install-pickle-in-python-3-6/48477988)
より

```
import sys
import numpy as np

src = sys.argv[1]  # path to your file

data = open(src).read().replace('\r\n', '\n') # read and replace file contents
dst = src + ".tmp"
open(dst, "w").write(data) # save a temporary file

world = pickle.load(open(dst, "rb"), encoding='latin1')
```

を適宜パスを変更し、解決。